# VBA: Code Pauses For Varying Lengths of Time With DoEvents

Tags: excel, vba, doevents

I have a procedure that generates reports based on user input provided on a user-form. I have implemented error handling, as one should, but one of my error handlers is not playing well with `DoEvents`. The issue is that my main sub `LoopGenrtReport`, which loops another sub, `GenerateReport`, freezes up for varying lengths of time, IF, the `GenerateReport` sub is exited due to an error. I say varying lengths, because sometimes it's 5 seconds, and other times it never moves to the next iteration of the loop.

I have tested removing the code for the progress bar and `Doevents`, and in doing so, I found that the procedure works exactly as intended.

I have also tested without `Application.Interactive`, but WITH the progress bar and `Doevents` to see if that might be the issue, but the same thing occurs.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub LoopGenrtReport(ByRef InPut_Array As Variant)
 
 Dim ii As Long
 Dim UBTailNum_Array As Long
 Dim Filtered_Array As Variant
 Dim LoopCounter As Long
 Dim pctdone As Single
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Interactive = False
 
        UBTailNum_Array = UBound(InPut_Array)
        
        'Sheet_Array is a public variable as are StartDate and End Date
        Filtered_Array = SubsetArray(Sheet_Array, StartDate, EndDate)
        
            If IsEmpty(Filtered_Array) Then
                MsgBox "No Transactions were found in the date range selected.", _
                vbCritical, "Error: No Transactions Found"
                GoTo ClearVariables
            End If
    
        'Release from memory
        Erase Sheet_Array
    
    'Show progress bar if more than one report _
    is being generated
    If UBTailNum_Array > 0 Then Call ShowPrgssBar

    For ii = LBound(InPut_Array) To UBound(InPut_Array)
            
            LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1
            
            pctdone = LoopCounter / (UBTailNum_Array + 1)
            
            With FrmProgress
                .LabelCaption.Caption = "Generating Report(s) " & LoopCounter & " of " & UBTailNum_Array + 1
                .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
            End With
            DoEvents
            
            Call GenerateReport(Filtered_Array, CStr(InPut_Array(ii)))
        
    Next ii
    
ClearVariables:
    StartDate = Empty
    EndDate = Empty
    
    ii = Empty
    InPut_Array = Empty
    UBTailNum_Array = Empty
    Filtered_Array = Empty
    LoopCounter = Empty
    pctdone = Empty
    
    Application.Interactive = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

**Note:** This behavior occurs ONLY when I exit `GenerateReport` due to an error. The actual error is that no transactions were found for the current `InPut_Array(ii)` item. Expected behavior would be to just move the next iteration of the loop in the main sub without issue. There is nothing that would affect the main sub if the called sub is exited.

I have spent quite a long time trying to resolve the issue to no avail. Any ideas, suggestions, or answers would be greatly appreciated.

As Per Request of @Spring Filip, a condensed version of the called sub, `GenerateReport` has been provided below.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module
 
Sub GenerateReport(ByRef Source_Array As Variant, ByRef KeyTailNum As String)
 
 Dim i As Long
 Dim CompositeKey As String
 Dim Dict1 As Dictionary
 Dim ItemComp_Array As Variant
 
 Dim Coll As Collection

    Set Dict1 = New Dictionary
        Dict1.CompareMode = TextCompare
        
    Set Coll = New Collection

            ' Build dictionary that summarizes transactions
            For i = LBound(Source_Array, 1) To UBound(Source_Array, 1)
                    
                If Source_Array(i, 6) = KeyTailNum Then
                    
                    CompositeKey = vbNullString
                    
                    If Source_Array(i, 5) <> "MRO VENDOR" Then
                            
                            If Source_Array(i, 5) = "ISSUE FROM STOCK" Then
                                'buid collection of IFS PNs
                                Coll.Add Source_Array(i, 1)
                            End If
                            
                            'CompositeKey = PN,PO,Amount,Exp Type
                            CompositeKey = Join(Array(Source_Array(i, 1), _             
                                                Source_Array(i, 4), _
                                                Abs(Source_Array(i, 3)), _
                                                Source_Array(i, 5), KeyTailNum), "~~")
                            
                            If Dict1.Exists(CompositeKey) Then
                            
                                ItemComp_Array = Split(Dict1.Item(CompositeKey), "~~")
                                             
                                Dict1.Item(CompositeKey) = Join(Array(ItemComp_Array(0), _
                                                            ItemComp_Array(1), _
                                                            (CDbl(ItemComp_Array(2) + CDbl(Source_Array(i, 3)))), _
                                                            ItemComp_Array(3), _
                                                            ItemComp_Array(4), 0), "~~")
                                
                            Else
                                'Item = PN, PN Des, Amount, Exp Cat, Count, Place holder for averages  
                                Dict1.Add CompositeKey, Join(Array(Source_Array(i, 1), _
                                                            Source_Array(i, 2), _
                                                            CDbl(Source_Array(i, 3)), _
                                                            Source_Array(i, 5), _
                                                            1, 0), "~~")
                                
                            End If
                        
                    Else
                            'Key = Exp Alpha Name; PN/Exp Remark; Rec Unique ID; Tail Number
                            CompositeKey = Join(Array(Source_Array(i, 1), _
                                            Source_Array(i, 2), Source_Array(i, 7), KeyTailNum), "~~")
    
                            If Not Dict1.Exists(CompositeKey) Then
                                
                                'Item = Exp Alpha Name; PN/Exp Remark; Amount; Exp Typ; Account;Rec Unique Id
                                Dict1.Add CompositeKey, Join(Array(Source_Array(i, 1), _
                                                            Source_Array(i, 2), _
                                                            CDbl(Source_Array(i, 3)), _
                                                            Source_Array(i, 5), _
                                                            Source_Array(i, 8), _
                                                            Source_Array(i, 7)), "~~")
                                
            
                            End If

                    End If
                    
                End If
            Next i

                'Errors_Coll is public, BoolExitGenRprt is public
                '**************************************************************************************************
                'Conditional Exit of Sub 
                '**************************************************************************************************
                'If there are no transactions found for this tail then go to the Next Tail Number if there is one
                If Dict1.Count = 0 Then
                    Errors_Coll.Add KeyTailNum
                    BoolExitGenRprt = True
                    GoTo ClearAllVariables
                End If
                '**************************************************************************************************
                '**************************************************************************************************
 
        
            'Begin Other code to be executed
            |
            |
            |
            |
            |
            |
            |
            |
            'End Other code to be excuted'


ClearAllVariables:
            'Clear Variables
            i = Empty
            Set Dict1 = Nothing
            CompositeKey = Empty
            ItemComp_Array = Empty
            Source_Array = Empty
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you also provide `Sub GenerateReport`, where the problematic `DoEvents` method is called?

Comment: I can, but I would warn that it is very lengthy and there are many things that would be out of context.

Comment: Then please create a minimal working example, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @SpringFilip, done. Check out the edit.

Comment: Thanks. As I am looking at the code you provided, I cannot see the `doEvents` call in the `Sub GenerateReport`. Also there isn't any real error handling using keywords `On Error ...`, anywhere in the code provided.

Comment: You're most welcome. I genuinely appreciate you taking the time. The `DoEvents` Call is only in the `LoopGenrtReport` sub. My error handler, in the `GenerateReport` sub, conditionally exits the sub and is denoted between the asterisk lines. The idea is that if `Dict1.Count =  0` Then I want to exit the sub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189973/discussion-between-spring-filip-and-rickmanalexander).

Comment: Why are you calling` DoEvents` in the first place?

Comment: @SpringFilip Unfortunately I am on my companies network which blocks Stockoverflow chats. So, I wouldn't be able  to chat until I get home this evening around 4:30 EST. My apologies.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am using `DoEvents` to Update the progress bar. If you think I don't need it though, I would be glad to get rid of it, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Enigmativity 's Comment made me question why I am even using `DoEvents` in the first place, so I said to myself, "Self, What if you just get rid of `DoEvents` altogether and use the `Sleep` Windows API function at a 10ms increment instead of `DoEvents`?" Well, that's just what I did, with the addition of `FrmProgress.Repaint` and it prevents Excel from freezing for extended periods of time all while updating the progress bar like I need it to.

The only issue is that it when the `GenerateReport` is exited due to my defined error, there is still a bit of a lag, but compared to what it was doing before, I can live with it.

If any one else has a better idea, or if you think my idea will not work like I am hoping it will, then please let me know. I am 100% open to other ideas or solutions.

**Amended code:**

```
Private Sub LoopGenrtReport(ByRef InPut_Array As Variant)

 Dim ii As Long
 Dim UBTailNum_Array As Long
 Dim Filtered_Array As Variant
 Dim LoopCounter As Long
 Dim pctdone As Single

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Interactive = False

        UBTailNum_Array = UBound(InPut_Array)

        'Sheet_Array is a public variable as are StartDate and End Date
        Filtered_Array = SubsetArray(Sheet_Array, StartDate, EndDate)

            If IsEmpty(Filtered_Array) Then
                MsgBox "No Transactions were found in the date range selected.", _
                vbCritical, "Error: No Transactions Found"
                GoTo ClearVariables
            End If

        'Release from memory
        Erase Sheet_Array

    'Show progress bar if more than one report _
    is being generated
    If UBTailNum_Array > 0 Then Call ShowPrgssBar

    For ii = LBound(InPut_Array) To UBound(InPut_Array)

            LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1

            pctdone = LoopCounter / (UBTailNum_Array + 1)

            With FrmProgress
                .LabelCaption.Caption = "Generating Report(s) " & LoopCounter & " of " & UBTailNum_Array + 1
                .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
            End With

            '***********************************
            'Added these in place of 'DoEvents'
            FrmProgress.Repaint
            Call Sleep (10)
            '***********************************

            Call GenerateReport(Filtered_Array, CStr(InPut_Array(ii)))

    Next ii

ClearVariables:
    StartDate = Empty
    EndDate = Empty

    ii = Empty
    InPut_Array = Empty
    UBTailNum_Array = Empty
    Filtered_Array = Empty
    LoopCounter = Empty
    pctdone = Empty

    Application.Interactive = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Windows API Functions/subs:**

```
#If VBA7 Then 
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)

#Else

    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)

#End If
```